# Getting a TypeError when trying to save Optuna.Study in an optimize callback

Tags: python, pytorch, optuna

I'm running some Optuna study, and when I try to save it with `joblib.dump`, I'm getting the following:

> TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object

I also try to `pickle.dump(study, open('name.pkl', 'wb'))`, but I'm getting the same in both cases
EDIT: now I understood it has something to do with the fact I'm doing it in a callback, otherwise it works
I am training a custom PyTorch model, everything else seem to work in terms of the study itself.. but when I try to save it I get the above error.
I'm kind of clueless in terms of how to debug it.

Environment:

- QubeOS with debian 10 VM
- Python 3.8
- PyTorch 1.5
- Optuna 2.0
  edited:
  this is the stacktrace:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-f2187f915338>", line 1, in <module>
    joblib.dump(study, f'{filepath}.pkl')
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 480, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 485, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 601, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 715, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 969, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 995, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 601, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 715, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 969, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 995, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 601, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 715, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 969, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 995, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/torch_38/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 576, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

Comment: Are you using the progress bar, that is passing `show_progress_bar=True` to `Study.optimize` ? If so, passing  `False` instead should circumvent the issue. This is because the progress bar is held indirectly by a `Study` object, and I'm afraid it cannot be pickled. This is one of the reasons why the progress bar is experimental.

Comment: thanks, but it is not my case, I'm not using the progress_bar

Comment: Some more context might help in that case. Could you provide reproduction code for the objective function and/or the callback? I can seemingly not reproduce the error on a similar environment except for the OS.